# How to get feature names from ELI5 when transformer includes an embedded pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, eli5

The [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/) library provides the function `transform_feature_names` to retrieve the feature names for the output of an [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/) transformer. The [documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries/sklearn.html#transformation-pipelines) says that the function works out of the box when the transformer includes nested Pipelines.

I'm trying to get the function to work on a simplified version of the example in the [answer to SO 57528350](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534118/). My simplified example doesn't need `Pipeline`, but in real life I will need it in order to add steps to `categorical_transformer`, and I will also want to add transformers to the `ColumnTransformer`.

```
import eli5
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

X_train = pd.DataFrame({'age': [23, 12, 12, 18],
                        'gender': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
                        'income': ['high', 'low', 'low', 'medium'],
                        'y': [0, 1, 1, 1]})

categorical_features = ['gender', 'income']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

transformers=[('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)]
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers)
X_train_transformed = preprocessor.fit(X_train)

eli5.transform_feature_names(preprocessor, list(X_train.columns))
```

This dies with the message

> AttributeError: Transformer categorical (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.

Since the `Pipeline` is nested in the `ColumnTransformer`, I understood from the ELI5 documentation that it would be handled.

Do I need to create a modified version of `Pipeline` with a `get_feature_names` method or make other custom modifications in order to take advantage of the ELI5 function?

I'm using python 3.7.6, eli5 0.10.1, pandas 0.25.3, and sklearn 0.22.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that eli5 is relying on the `ColumnTransformer` method `get_feature_names`, which itself asks the `Pipeline` to `get_feature_names`, which is not yet implemented in sklearn.

[I've opened an Issue with eli5 with your example.](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/issues/382)

One possible fix: adding a `transform_feature_names` dispatch for `ColumnTransformer`; this can be just a modification of its existing `get_feature_names` to call for eli5 `transform_feature_names` for each of its component transformers (instead of sklearn's own `get_feature_names`).  The below seems to work, although I'm not sure how to handle when `input_names` differs from the training dataframe columns, available in the `ColumnTransformer` as `_df_columns`.

```
from eli5 import transform_feature_names

@transform_feature_names.register(ColumnTransformer)
def col_tfm_names(transformer, in_names=None):
    if in_names is None:
        from eli5.sklearn.utils import get_feature_names
        # generate default feature names
        in_names = get_feature_names(transformer, num_features=transformer._n_features)
    # return a list of strings derived from in_names
    feature_names = []
    for name, trans, column, _ in transformer._iter(fitted=True):
        if hasattr(transformer, '_df_columns'):
            if ((not isinstance(column, slice))
                    and all(isinstance(col, str) for col in column)):
                names = column
            else:
                names = transformer._df_columns[column]
        else:
            indices = np.arange(transformer._n_features)
            names = ['x%d' % i for i in indices[column]]
        # erm, want to be able to override with in_names maybe???

        if trans == 'drop' or (
                hasattr(column, '__len__') and not len(column)):
            continue
        if trans == 'passthrough':
            feature_names.extend(names)
            continue
        feature_names.extend([name + "__" + f for f in
                              transform_feature_names(trans, in_names=names)])
    return feature_names
```

I also needed to create a dispatch for `OneHotEncoder`, because its `get_feature_names` needs the parameter `input_features`:

```
@transform_feature_names.register(OneHotEncoder)
def _ohe_names(est, in_names=None):
    return est.get_feature_names(input_features=in_names)
```

Relevant links:
https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html#eli5.transform_feature_names
https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/4839d1927c4a68aeff051935d1d4d8a4fb69b46d/eli5/sklearn/transform.py